# Function that returns a function pointer syntax

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, function-pointers

I'm having trouble with the following syntax in C:

```
float (*func(unsigned id))(float value) {
    ...
}
```

I understand that:

- It is a definition of a function called `func`
- `func` accepts one argument of type `unsigned` called `id`
- `func` returns a pointer to a function that looks like: `float f(float value)`

But I don't understand why the return value of `f` (the returned function pointer) is separated from its argument list.

Also, is: `func(unsigned id)` an expression that evaluates to some pointer? Is this the reason why `(*func(unsigned id))` works?

Can someone clarify this syntax step by step?

Comment: Not worth adding as an answer, but `cdecl` is a command line tool that will explain this for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression `func(id)` returns a pointer to a function that takes a float as argument and returns a float.

```
float(*f)(float v);  // pointer to a function 
float val;     

f = func(3);       // returns a pointer to a function 
val = (*f)(3.14);  // calls the function pointed to with argument 3.14
```

Of course, you could rewrite the last statement:

```
val = (*func(3))(3.14);  // take the ptr returned by func(3) and call the function pointed to.
```

If you have a function like:

```
float fct1 (float v) { return 2.0f*v+3.1f; }
```

you could write:

```
f = fct1;       // reassign the pointer to function f to the adress of fct1
```

Let's look at the syntax.  The C11 standard (draft N1570) states in 6.5.2.2 point 1: that *"The expression that denotes the called function) shall have type pointer to function"* and in point 3 that:  *"A postfix expression followed by parentheses () containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of expressions is a function call."*

This covers of course the usual cases:

```
 val = fct1 (3.14);   // fct1 is the function designator which adresses the function  
 val = (*f) (3.14);  // (*f) the dereferenced function pointer, so it addresses the function
```

But the following is also valid according to standard:

```
 val  = f(3.14);    //  This works as well, because f is a pointer to a function
 val = func(3)(3.14)  // works also because func(3) is a pointer to a function
```

However first expression is ambiguous for the human reader, who might think of f as a function designator, expecting it to be defined somewhere.  And the second is unusual as well. Furthermore, earlier versions of C didn't recognize them.  My K&R edition for 1978 required the form (*f)() to call a function pointer.

A last syntactic remark:  If you would define f as `float *f (float);` it wouldn't be understood as a pointer to a function, but as a forward declaration of a plain function called f and returning a pointer to float.  Why ?  Because the [C precedence rules](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/104/fall06/burt/precedenceTable.html) give `()` a higer precedence than `*` meaning that the compiler would understand it as `(float *)(f(float))`.  This is why an explicit parenthesis is required to show that `(*f)` is the function pointer.

Answer (score 8):

Take this step-by-step with help from [C gibberish ↔ English](http://cdecl.org)

```
float (*func(unsigned id))(float value) { ... }
```

First replace "func" with "f" as that nifty web-site has trouble with "func" and then remove parameter names.

```
float (*f(unsigned ))(float )
// declare f as function (unsigned) returning pointer to function (float) returning float
```

From this, `f` is function declaration that takes an `unsigned id`.    That's the `f(unsigned )` part.

It returns a variable `x` as if it was declared `float (*x)(float )`.  The first half of this is, as OP observed, is separate from the 2nd half in the original declaration of the function.

Suggest experiment with that site remembering to not use "func"

Examples:

```
int f2(unsigned ); 
// declare f2 as function (unsigned) returning int
int (*f3(unsigned ));
// declare f3 as function (unsigned) returning pointer to int
int (*f4)(unsigned );
// declare f4 as pointer to function (unsigned) returning int
int (*f5(unsigned ))(char);
// declare f5 as function (unsigned) returning pointer to function (char) returning int
```

Comment: Very nice! So your `f3` is just the extended form of how we all know it - `int *f3(unsigned)`?

Comment: @barak manos  Yes - the same.  Added `f3` as it would help to explain OP's `(*func(unsigned id))`.

Comment: Got it. Never had to return a function-pointer. I guess that's why the syntax looked so unreadable. It seems pretty pointless to do that anyway. I can't really think of any scenario in which I would need to return a function-pointer... Thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
   float (*func(unsigned id))(float value);
```

Is the **declaration** of a function which takes an **unsigned int** as an **argument** and returns a **pointer to a function**.

The function to which the pointer  points to (the function `f`) takes one **float as argument** and **returns float**. It's declaration is:

```
float f(float value);
```

The **name** of the `func` function:

```
float (*func(unsigned id))(float value);
        ^^^^
```

The **argument** of the function `func`:

```
float (*func(unsigned id))(float value);
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The **return type** of the function `func`:

```
  float (*func(unsigned id))(float value);
  ^^^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If the function had **no argument** it would look like this:

```
float (*func())(float value);
```

**You asked**:*Also, is: `func(unsigned id)` an expression that evaluates to some pointer?*

**No**, it is the name `func` and the argument `(unsigned id)` of the function

Are you starting to see now what is `func`? It is a function which returns a pointer which points to another declared function.

I included the code in which you can explicitly see what is the return value of the `func` function compared with the referencing of the `f` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float f(float value);
float (*func(unsigned id))(float value);

int main()
{

    /* print the address of the f function
     * using the return value of function func
     */
    printf("func return value: %p\n\n", func(2)); 




      /* print the address of the f function referencing
       * its address
       */
     printf("referencing f address: %p\n", &f); 

    return 0;
}

float (*func(unsigned id))(float value)
{
    printf("Original function with argument id = %d called\n", id);
    return f;
}

float f(float value)
{
    printf("f function\n");
    return 0.1;
}
```